# Why url-generator does not preserve xml comments when using url with file: protocol?

Tags: orbeon

I am using orbeon-cli.jar for calling my pipeline. It's currently in version 3.8. However, during the process, my xml file has no xml comment anymore. I upgrade to orbeon 3.9 according to the [announcement](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/39#TOC-XML-comments-in-XPL-and-XForms) that "Orbeon Forms now has XML / HTML comments support in XPL and in the XForms engine." In fact it does, but in a strange way.

I simplify the process to a simple xpl file, where it only read the xml file and write it down. Here is my test:
1. I use relative path in : the output xml has xml comments, as expected.

```
<p:processor name="oxf:url-generator">
      <p:input name="config">
          <config>
              <url>export.xml</url>
          </config>
      </p:input>
      <p:output name="data" id="main-input"/>
  </p:processor>
  <p:processor name="oxf:xml-converter">
       <p:input name="config">
           <config>
               <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
           </config>
       </p:input>
       <p:input name="data" href="#main-input"/>
       <p:output name="data" id="input-converted"/>
  </p:processor> 
  <p:processor name="oxf:file-serializer">
    <p:input name="config">
        <config>
          <file>file_written_relative_path.xml</file>
        </config>
    </p:input>
    <p:input name="data" href="#input-converted"/>
  </p:processor>
```

2. But in fact, what we need is a absolute-path in , as:

```
<p:processor name="oxf:url-generator">
    <p:input name="config">
        <config>
          <url>file:///D:/path/to/file/export.xml</url>
          <mode>xml</mode>
          <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
          <force-encoding>true</force-encoding>
          <content-type>application/xml</content-type>
          <force-content-type>true</force-content-type>
          <handle-lexical>true</handle-lexical><!-- 'true' is the default value anyway -->
          <cache-control>
            <use-local-cache>false</use-local-cache>
          </cache-control>
        </config>
    </p:input>
    <p:output name="data" id="main-input-absolute"/>
  </p:processor>

  <p:processor name="oxf:xml-converter">
       <p:input name="config">
           <config>
               <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
           </config>
       </p:input>
       <p:input name="data" href="#main-input-absolute"/>
       <p:output name="data" id="input-absolute-converted"/>
  </p:processor> 
  <p:processor name="oxf:file-serializer">
    <p:input name="config">
        <config>
          <file>file_written_absolute_path.xml</file>
        </config>
    </p:input>
    <p:input name="data" href="#input-absolute-converted"/>
  </p:processor>
```

To me, it seems like "url-generator" has different ways to load file in those cases. Even though I have tried all possible configs for url-generator in [2], it does not keep all comments as in [1]. Why it doesn't? Is it a bug? Is there any way to workaround? Or is there some where else it can be configured?

Comment: Hi Thao, is there any reason you're not upgrading to 2018.2, that is to the latest release? I'm asking because if this is an issue that needs to be fixed, this will be done on the latest code, so the first step would be to reproduce it with the latest release.

Comment: Orbeon Forms 3.9 is [almost 8-year-old](https://doc.orbeon.com/release-history). It is unlikely that any bug will be fixed on that version.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Erik, I have checked with 4.5 CE as well, no difference. We want to stick to version 3 is because of the custom processors we wrote, will cost more to rebuilt all for version 4, right?

Comment: For reference, this is also discussed [here](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Why-url-generator-does-not-preserve-xml-comments-when-using-url-with-file-protocol-td4664344.html).